# Why is the print statement running twice?

Tags: python, control-flow

[image of the executed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsUTJ.png)The code executes, but the print statements run twice. Can someone explain why is it so?

```
n = input('you are lost in the woods, turn left or right\n**********\n**********\n:)\n**********\n**********\n')
m = 0
if n == 'right':
    while n == 'right' and m < 2:
        n = input('you are lost in the woods, turn left or right:')
        m += 1
    print('**********\n***    ***\n (/⚬⎯￮)/ ∐\n**********\n**********')
if n == 'left':
    print('You got out of the woods')
```

I want the first print statement to run, if the input is 'right' thrice.
I want the second print statement to run, if the input is 'left'.

The problem is, if i enter 'right', the third time the print statement in the first if block is executing twice. If i enter 'left', the print statement in the second if block executes twice.

Comment: Which `print` statement runs twice, under what circumstances?

Comment: what input did you give for n?

Comment: Could you add the output too?

Comment: There is no such input case where any single `print` statement would run twice in your code.

Comment: Seems like a jupyter issue to me, restart your kernel or reload the page or something. As I said above, that double output is not coming from your code.

Answer (score 1):

here is the correct code:

```
n = input('you are lost in the woods, turn left or right\n**********\n**********\n:)\n**********\n**********\n')
m = 0
if n == 'right':
    while n == 'right' and m < 1:
        n = input('you are lost in the woods, turn left or right:')
        m += 1
    print('**********\n***    ***\n (/⚬⎯￮)/ ∐\n**********\n**********')
if n == 'left':
    print('You got out of the woods')
```

m is 0 in the beginning and you did

```
while n == 'right' and m < 2:
```

Comment: you are just lowering the times the while loop runs. The problem still remains.